# Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::orderBy does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I have a piece of code like this:

```
public function products()
{
    $product = DB::table('products')->where('is_active', NULL)->get();
    if($price = request('entityprice')){
        $product->orderBy('entityprice', $price);
    }
    // $products = DB::table('products')->where('is_active', NULL)->find($id);
    // dd($product);
    return view('products', compact('product'));
}
```

I got the following error:

```
Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::orderBy does not exist.
```

I have front page

```
 <a href="?entityprice=desc">Sort by price descending</a>
 <a href="?entityprice=asc">Sort by price</a>
```

Please help me)))

Comment: use $product= $product->get() at last.


return view('products', compact('product'));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one

```
public function products()
{
    $product = DB::table('products')->where('is_active', NULL);
    if($price = request('entityprice')){
        $product->orderBy('entityprice', $price);
    }

    return view('products', ['product' => $product->get()]);
}
```

Comment: Correct. But I think it is better to mention the reason as well why OP was facing that issue.

Answer (score 2):

Actually `orderBy` is not defined for `Collection`, you have to use `sortBy`.

A better approach is to use `orderBy` with your query. and yes, you have an if statement. So instead of `if` statement, replace it with `when` method which will organize your query and make it a little better and more readable:

```
public function products()    
{
    $product = DB::table('products')
            ->where('is_active', NULL)
            ->when(request('entityprice', false), 
                function($query, $entityprice){
                    return $query->orderBy('entityprice', $entityprice);
                })
            ->get()
    return view('products', compact('product'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code,

```
public function products()
{
    $product = DB::table('products')->where('is_active', NULL);
    if($price = request('entityprice')){
        $product->orderBy('entityprice', $price)->get();
    }
    // $products = DB::table('products')->where('is_active', NULL)->find($id);
    // dd($product);
    return view('products', compact('product'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a logical error in code

```
public function products()
{
 $product = DB::table('products')->where('is_active', NULL);
 if($price = request('entityprice')){
    $product->orderBy('entityprice', $price);
 }
 $prod = $product->get();
// $products = DB::table('products')->where('is_active', NULL)->find($id);
// dd($product);
return view('products', compact('prod'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
public function products()
{
    $product = DB::table('products')->where('is_active', NULL)->get();
    if($price = request('entityprice')){
        $product->orderBy('entityprice', $price);
    }
$products = $products->get();
    // $products = DB::table('products')->where('is_active', NULL)->find($id);
    // dd($product);
    return view('products', compact('product'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't use `orderBy` with a collection. You should use `orderBy` before `get()` or use `sortBy` with this collection.
Modify it:

```
public function products()
{
    $product = DB::table('products')->where('is_active', NULL);
    if($price = request('entityprice')) {
        $product->orderBy('entityprice', $price);
    }

    return view('products', ['product' => $product->get()]);
}
```

or

```
public function products()
{
    $product = DB::table('products')->where('is_active', NULL)->get();
    if($price = request('entityprice')) {
        $product->sortBy('entityprice', $price);
    }

    return view('products', ['product' => $product->get()]);
}
```

The first solution will order in the query statement. And the last solution will order in the collection.